# Join all rows from two different tables MySQL

Tags: mysql, join, union

I've been trying to join all the rows from two different tables. I've tried UNION and LEFT JOIN.

Right now I've just been using two separate queries and had one display after the other. I would like to merge the two queries to display at the same time.

table 1 is called 'approves' and table 2 is called 'comments'.

> approves 
>    - id 
>    - postID 
>    - postUserID 
>    - userID
>
> comments 
>    - id 
>    - postID 
>    - postUserID 
>    - userID 
>    - comment 
>    - date

Comment: Can you post the table structures?  It is difficult to figure out what the tables will join on without any details

Comment: @IanQuinn edit your original question and post the table structure there, don't put it in the comments

Answer (score 6):

here would be an example of a UNION

```
select id, postID, postUserID, userID, comment, date from comments
union
select id, postID, postUserID, userID, null, null from approves
```

Comment: Okay, so once I have this, is there any way to determine which table the current record is coming from if I have this query in a WHILE loop that is fetching the rows?

Comment: yes - add another arbitrary column with say a hardcoded 1 in the first and a 2 in the second.. you can use that to tell.

Answer (score 0):

Can you insert the SQL that you are using? Union would combine both tables, a join would in turn take all the rows from table and combine all associated rows. JOIN defaults to an inner join. UNION is will in effect combine the results from two tables. If you want all rows fromt able a, and the corresponding comments from table b then use a left join.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your tables, it looks like you can `JOIN` the tables:

```
select *
from approves a
inner join comments c
    on a.userid = c.userid
    and a.postid = c.postid
```

I am guessing that you will need to join the tables on multiple columns based on the `postid` and the `userid`.

I used an `INNER JOIN` which will return all matching rows between both tables.  If you want to return only those records in the `approves` table, then you can use a `LEFT JOIN`.  If you need help learning join syntax, here is a great [visual explanation of joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).

You can use a `UNION` but would have to select what columns you want for each table since the number of columns in each query of a `UNION` must be equal.  So the `UNION` would be:

```
select id, postid, postUserId, userId, null as comment, null as date, 'approves' as Src
from approves 
union all
select id, postid, postUserId, userId, comment, date, 'comments' as src
from comments
```

Notice that I included an addition column called `src` which can be used to determine what table the data came from.

Comment: Tried this and I got a boolean error when I am using mysql_fetch_assoc

mysql_query("SELECT * FROM approves a INNER JOIN comments c ON a.userID = c.userID AND a.postID = c.postID WHERE postUserID = '$userID' && userID != '$userID' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,10");

Comment: @IanQuinn I am not sure what the error, but I have also included a `UNION` version to return the data